# Python dictを識別番号式にする

Tags: python

```
persons = [{"ID": 1001, "NAME": "YAMANE", "AGE": 31},
           {"ID": 1001, "NAME": "SHIMADA", "AGE": 51},
           {"ID": 1002, "NAME": "AMANE", "AGE": 13},
           {"ID": 1003, "NAME": "OKADA", "AGE": 21}]
```

が入っています。注目点としてIDは重複します。

こちらを↓のような形にしたいです。

```
persons[[1001][{"NAME": "YAMANE", "AGE": 31},{"NAME": "SHIMADA", "AGE": 51}],
      [1002][{"NAME": "AMANE", "AGE": 13}],
      [1003][{"NAME": "OKADA", "AGE": 21}]]
```

pymysqlのfetchallを使用すると、データベースの行ごとにdict形式で配列されます。

私が試して失敗した例：

```
person_box = []
for person in persons:
    person_box[person['ID']] = person
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

defaultdict使えばできるのではないでしょうか？

```
from collections import defaultdict

persons = [{"ID": 1001, "NAME": "YAMANE", "AGE": 31},
           {"ID": 1001, "NAME": "SHIMADA", "AGE": 51},
           {"ID": 1002, "NAME": "AMANE", "AGE": 13},
           {"ID": 1003, "NAME": "OKADA", "AGE": 21}]

person_box = defaultdict(list)
for person in persons:
    person_box[person['ID']].append(person)
```

Comment: 思い通りにできました。あまりCollectionsは使いたくありませんでしたが、助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

別解として `itertools.groupby()` を使う方法などを。

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import pprint
>>> person_box = {
      k: [{i: j for i, j in d.iteritems() if i!='ID'} for d in v]
      for k, v in itertools.groupby(persons, key=lambda x: x['ID'])
    }
>>> pprint.pprint(person_box)
{1001: [{'AGE': 31, 'NAME': 'YAMANE'}, {'AGE': 51, 'NAME': 'SHIMADA'}],
 1002: [{'AGE': 13, 'NAME': 'AMANE'}],
 1003: [{'AGE': 21, 'NAME': 'OKADA'}]}
```